# Formato condicional

Tags: excel

Necesito aplicar un formato a celdas cuando se cumple una condición.

Tenemos el botón formato condicional y en más reglas, utilizar una fórmula para aplicar el formato.

Entonces la idea es:

Que tendríamos una celda **COSTE** multiplicada por **0.25 = valorPorcentaje**

Necesito que si mi **valorporcetaje** es menor al valor de la última celda donde pone **20 euros**, entonces se aplique un formato, por ejemplo que me pusiera color rojo de fondo.

Utilizo, esta fórmula que debería funcionar, pero no hay manera:

```
=PRODUCTO(M13;0,25) > R13
```

[image: mi tabla]

Hola
Vuelvo con esto porque ya veo que tengo algunos errores de concepto pero a ver si me podeis ayudar:

Quiero poner esta formula, si el resultado de mi ganacia es menor al resultado del coste por 25% pero no me acepta la formula, no se porque

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: *si mi valorporcetaje es menor*, pero en tu fórmula has puesto `>`.

Comment: Carlos, las ediciones debes hacerlas en tu pregunta, y [no en las respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/195562). Puedes hacer [clic aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/326907/edit) para añadir la información que desees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realmente no veo dónde tienes el problema:

Tienes el "COSTE" que quieres multiplicar por 0,25 y compararlo con un valor fijo,
según el resultado del producto sea menor o mayor quieres aplicarle un formato a la celda (o fila).

- Lo que puedes hacer es añadirle una regla:

[image]

- Lo siguiente es asignar la celda, columna o fila (en la imagen se muestra que solo está afectando a un grupo de celdas de la misma columna)
  [image]
- Este es el resultado que se espera:
  [image]

Recuerda que para que la condición se fije en un valor de una determinada casilla el valor seleccionado debe tener "$"

> $ sirve para fijar una fila o una columna o ambas en Excel.

(FUENTE: https://excelyvba.com/para-que-sirve-el-simbolo-en-una-formula/)

Comment: Gracis por la ayuda, veo que hay un problema con los formatos, si tengo los campos es general o string no funcionan las formulas, en todo caso gracias

Comment: @Carlos si tenes otra duda, hace una nueva pregunta. la edicion de una respuesta para agregar una pregunta no es correcto